# When i click save button to save a stored procedure then it occurs an error in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

The query is running well in query field and returns data. 
But when i want to put it on stored procedure then caused an error like the given screen shoot.[image: error reporting image]. 
Please help me, how can i solve this question.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mikrof`@`%` PROCEDURE `savingRelated`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(IF(`created_at` < '2017-09-30', 1, 0)) AS MembersInLastMonth,
     SUM(IF(`created_at` between '2017-10-01'AND '2017-10-15', 1, 0)) AS MembersInCurrentMonth,
     SUM(IF(`created_at` <= '2017-10-30', 1, 0)) AS gg,
     SUM(IF(((`IsActive`=0) && (`created_at` between '2017-10-01'AND '2017-10-15')), 1, 0)) AS MembersCancelInCurrentMonth FROM members
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`mikrof`@`%` PROCEDURE `savingRelated`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(IF(`created_at` < '2017-09-30', 1, 0)) AS MembersInLastMonth,
     SUM(IF(`created_at` between '2017-10-01'AND '2017-10-15', 1, 0)) AS MembersInCurrentMonth,
     SUM(IF(`created_at` <= '2017-10-30', 1, 0)) AS gg,
     SUM(IF(((`IsActive`=0) && (`created_at` between '2017-10-01'AND '2017-10-15')), 1, 0)) AS MembersCancelInCurrentMonth FROM members;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```